# bitrix. add2backet. не добавляются товары в корзину

Tags: javascript, битрикс

При нажатии на кнопку "в корзину" вообще ничего не происходит
 http://mirmozaic.bget.ru/

Answer (score 1):

У Вас в каждом элементе каталога выводится сриптовый блок:

```
$(function(){
    $("#add2basket_new_select_form_60937").submit(function(){
        var form = $(this);
        $(window).resize(function(){
            modalHeight = $(window).height() / 2 - $("#bx_2782831418_60937_new").height() / 2 + $(window).scrollTop();
            $("#bx_2782831418_60937_new").css({
                "top" : modalHeight + "px"
            });
        });
        $(window).resize();
        $("#bx_2782831418_60937_new_body").fadeIn(300);
        $("#bx_2782831418_60937_new").fadeIn(300);

        quantityItem = form.find("#quantity_new_60937").attr("value");
        $("#bx_2782831418_60937_new .quantity").attr("value", quantityItem);
        return false;
    });
    $("#bx_2782831418_60937_new_close, #bx_2782831418_60937_new_body").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#bx_2782831418_60937_new_body").fadeOut(300);
        $("#bx_2782831418_60937_new").fadeOut(300);
    });
});
```

в котором Вы навешиваете свой обработчик на кнопку отправить и отменяете стандартное действие.

Затем Вы пытаетесь показать 2 блока которых не существует. И поэтому у Вас ничего не работает

```
$("#bx_2782831418_60937_new_body").fadeIn(300);
$("#bx_2782831418_60937_new").fadeIn(300);
```

Comment: я уже разобрался, спасибо. а не подскажете, как вывести доп. поля товара? Мне надо вывести размер (м2) в корзине. То есть, рядом с ценой вставить размер добавленного товара

Comment: Задайте отдельный вопрос, а ещё лучше посмотрите в документации— не сложная и не такая уж и необычная задача